# How to keep the previous TOTAL so that it would add to the new TOTAL

Tags: c++

I want the Total to add the previous total to the new total when the user decides to order another order.
The output that i'm getting is this:

Enter order: 022

Quantity: 1

Total: 80

Additional Order (y/n):y

Enter order: 022

Quantity: 1

Total: 80

Additional Order (y/n):n

---

But i want it like this:

Enter order: 022

Quantity: 1

Total: 80

Additional Order (y/n):y

Enter order: 022

Quantity: 1

Total: 160  <<<<<<<<<<<<<< It added the previous Total to the new order

Additional Order (y/n):n

Help pls.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <locale>

void displayTakeOrder(void);
main()
{
system("CLS");

displayTakeOrder();

system("Pause");
system("CLS");

}


void displayTakeOrder(void)
{
char dec = 'y';
while (dec == 'y')
{

int repeat, order,quantity,price;

printf("Entry Order: ");
scanf("%d",&order);

printf("\nQuantity: ");
scanf("%d",&quantity);

if (order == 11)
{
    price = 20;
}
else if (order == 22)
{
    price = 80;
}
else if (order == 33)
{
    price = 85;
}
else if (order == 44)
{
    price = 90;
}
else if (order == 55)
{
    price = 90;
}
else if (order == 66)
{
    price = 150;
}
else if (order == 77)
{
    price = 100;
}
else if (order == 88)
{
    price = 120;
}
else if (order == 99)
{
    price = 130;
}
else if (order == 100)
{
    price = 120;
}
else
{
    price = 0;
}


int total = (price*quantity);
int total1 = 0;
total1 = total1 + total;
printf("\nTotal: %d",total1);

printf("\n\nAdditional Order?(Press y or n): ");
scanf("%s",&dec);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting wrong answer because in each iteration of the while loop, you are resetting the variable **`total1`** to 0.

So, just declare it before the while loop as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <locale>

void displayTakeOrder(void);
int main(){

    system("CLS");

    displayTakeOrder();

    system("Pause");
    system("CLS");

    return 0;
}


void displayTakeOrder(void){

    char dec = 'y';

    int total1 = 0; // Declaring total1 before the while loop

    while (dec == 'y'){

        int repeat, order,quantity,price;

        printf("Entry Order: ");
        scanf("%d",&order);

        printf("\nQuantity: ");
        scanf("%d",&quantity);

        if (order == 11)
        {
            price = 20;
        }
        else if (order == 22)
        {
            price = 80;
        }
        else if (order == 33)
        {
            price = 85;
        }
        else if (order == 44)
        {
            price = 90;
        }
        else if (order == 55)
        {
            price = 90;
        }
        else if (order == 66)
        {
            price = 150;
        }
        else if (order == 77)
        {
            price = 100;
        }
        else if (order == 88)
        {
            price = 120;
        }
        else if (order == 99)
        {
            price = 130;
        }
        else if (order == 100)
        {
            price = 120;
        }
        else
        {
            price = 0;
        }


        int total = (price*quantity);

        total1 = total1 + total;
        printf("\nTotal: %d",total1);

        printf("\n\nAdditional Order?(Press y or n): ");
        scanf("%s",&dec);
    }
}
```